# issue selecting only the specific elements within a div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using #acts h3, p to select only the H3's and P's inside of the div (id=acts). But it's also selecting P and h3 tags outside of the 'acts' div?
Yet it works just fine when I select them one at a time, like this

```
#acts h3
 {
  color: red;
}

#acts p {
  color: red;
}
```

but not when I try to select them at once, what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, every comma works as beginning with a complete new selector, and not in the way you expect it to work.

This means that your selector `#acts h3, p` selects both `#acts h3` & `p`, the latter targeting all `p` elements.

Instead your selector should look like this:

```
#acts h3, #acts p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Also: `#acts :is(h3, p)` would work, as would  `#acts :where(h3, p)` the only difference being that `:where()` doesn't affect specificity.

Comment: While this is true, it's only supported in major browsers since the beginning of 2021, which might be an issue, especially with Safari being bound to OS updates. Before that, it was only supported with the non-standard vendor prefix `:-webkit-any` which is the reason I don't use it yet in most of my project.

Comment: Yeah, there are reasons not to use it, and compatibility to consider; but it's just so pretty..!

Comment: Web Development would be boring without weird compatibility issues, support for older browsers and fighting with Safari.